# How to send a custom message using groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, slack

I need to read a jenkins build console output and grep a certain portion and send it to slack? Beginnner to groovy. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    notifyStarted() //Function to grep the console log

    def notifyStarted() {

      def loggg = manager.build.log
        loggg.split('\n')               // Split into lines
       .dropWhile { !(it ==~ /----*.+/) }  // Drop all lines before the text
       .drop(1)
       .takeWhile { !(it ==~ /----*.+/) }
        .each {
         manager.listener.logger.println(it)
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue? what is your input and expected output?

Comment: Jenkins build console log text is the input. I just want the method to send slack message using groovy.

Comment: See, this could help you https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/slacknotify/slackNotify.groovy

Comment: See sendMessage() and Post() methods as well here https://github.com/bdclark/rundeck-slack-notification/blob/master/SlackNotification.groovy

Comment: Trying them out. Thanks a lot @NitinDhomse

Comment: Adding sh command inside jenkins groovy script gives me an error as 'groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.sh() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload=${payload}' ${slackURL}]' @NitinDhomse

Comment: Script1 is of type String which don't have the sh() method, what you are trying? I don't know the context.